# I cannot convert yolov8-pose to tensorRT

Tags: tensorrt, yolov8

`from ultralytics import YOLO

## Load a model

model = YOLO('yolov8n-pose.pt')  # load an official model

## Export the model

model.export(format='engine')`

This is the code that I am using. This gave this error:

`Ultralytics YOLOv8.0.110  Python-3.9.16 torch-2.0.1+cu118 CPU
YOLOv8n-pose summary (fused): 187 layers, 3289964 parameters, 0 gradients

PyTorch: starting from yolov8n-pose.pt with input shape (1, 3, 640, 640) BCHW and output shape(s) (1, 56, 8400) (6.5 MB)
TensorRT: export failure  0.0s: export running on CPU but must be on GPU, i.e. use 'device=0'`

Then I enabled CUDA support.
See the attached image.

I was expecting it to convert to engine[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC2Sj.png)

Answer (score 0):

at the last line you have to change

```
model.export(format = 'engine', device = 0)
```

This is also stated in error msg but make sure tersorrt is installed